# When are $9^{n} - 2$ and $9^{n} + 2$ both prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Inspired by the discussion at a [since-deleted thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/math/comments/yeiq8/when_are_9n_2_and_9n_2_both_prime/):

> **Question:** For $n > 2$, are  $9^{n} - 2$ and $9^{n} + 2$ ever both prime?"

It seems that many different techniques were tried, ranging from Wilson's Theorem to a generalization of Clement's Theorem, and by looking at a couple of relevant OEIS sequences ([A090649](http://oeis.org/A090649); [A128455](http://oeis.org/A128455)).

Note that $9^{n} + 2$ is prime for $n$ beginning with:

$$0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 12, 13, 18, 49, 55, 63, 193, 247, \ldots$$

Similarly, $9^{n}-2$ is prime for $n$ beginning with:

$$1, 2, 3, 11, 45, 51, 260, 324, 390, 393, 1112, 3092, 4445, 10373 \ldots$$

Comment: Possibly never, just for statistical reasons (and thus possibly hopeless to prove).  A random number around $x$ is prime with probability $1/\log(x)$.  So we expect each of $9^n \pm 2$ to be prime with probability around $C_\pm/n$ for some constants $C_\pm$ (not just $1/\log 9$, because
$9^n \pm 2$ is coprime to $30$, one is a multiple of $7$ one-third of the time
but the other never is, "etc.").
So we might expect each of $9^n\pm 2$ to be prime infinitely often
but rarely (since $\sum_n 1/n$ diverges but slowly), but only finitely
many cases where both are prime (since $\sum_n 1/n^2<\infty$).

Comment: Echoing @Noam's comment: this sort of thing is very delicate, in our present state of knowledge. It seems at the very edge of true-or-false, so that innocent changes might make the answer flip-flop. @Noam's "probabilistic" point exemplifies why we currently oughtn't expect systematic answers to such questions, and perhaps never can, even after many historically-difficult things are settled. That is, to my perception, such ultra-particular questions are incredibly intractable...

Comment: Vote to close as 'too localized.' MO is not for contest problems and alike (it seems not an actual contest but still). Also this seems even a current/recent one.   

Comment: ... or we need a tag for "pointlessly intractable"? But maybe it is informative to explain why experienced people would find an innocent-sounding question intractable? I don't know ...

Comment: The person who asked on reddit emailed the person who proposed this question in PME to see if there was a already a solution in mind.  I don't see the harm in discussing ideas in any case.

Comment: @paul garrett: well, yes, but this *was already explained* on reddit even *before* the question was asked here. So, with this info at hand it is *clearly* off-topic. Since either there is some neat (elementary) trick or it is intractable (well or there is some example somewhere). @generalmath: one could consider it a waste  frontpage space on MO do redo some dicussion that already takes place elsewhere.  

Comment: I had a typo leaving both as -2 , later somebody changed the - to + in the wrong series, its been fixed now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I emailed the problem proposer, and he responded: "I do not have a solution to part d but hoped some insightful reader/solver would succeed. It is unusual for the editor to allow such a item but in this case he was convinced that investigating it would have merit!"

Comment: Oh well... But, thanks @Benjamin Dickmann for following up on this! Any suggestions on what to do now with this question? (Other than closing it.) 
Any volunteer for turning the comments into a (CW) answer? (I might do it myself, but once got 'flamed' for voting to close *and* answering. So, I'd prefer to avoid this.)

Answer (score 9):

A solution was ultimately published in the *Pi Mu Epsilon Journal*, *13*(7), Fall 2012, pp. 431 ([**JSTOR**](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24340680)).

It was attributed to **Paul S. Bruckman** (separate *PME* [**interview**](http://www.pme-math.org/journal/bruckmaninterview.html)) and reads, in part, as follows.

---

[image]

Comment: Looks like I'm a bit dense today. How exactly do $p=1+(20a+1)6, q=1+(12b+1)10$ imply $7\mid p$ and $11\mid q$? ($n$ is an obvious misprint). Also why to call the same number $a$ and $b$? All I understand is that $9^n\equiv 9(120)$, i.e., $40\mid 9^{n-1}-1$, i.e., $n$ is odd, which hardly helps with divisibility of $9^n-2$ by $7$ since the period is $3$.

Comment: Looks suspicious to me. In particular, how could it be possible that $p=103\pmod{120}$? This would imply $5\mid9^n$, weird!

Comment: Yes, it seems that the "solution" published in PME is incorrect. Not sure if I should edit to make that clear or contact the journal or...? [Unfortunately, the person who submitted this solution has passed away.] I was long skeptical that a simple solution existed, since the proposer claimed not to have a solution, and I worked quite hard on it before submitting parts abc without d. [Hence am listed in the journal as having submitted a "partial solution"...]

Comment: (c) is trivial: just put $n=1+15m, m=1,2,\dots$. I wonder what was the point of formulating (a) and (b) separately. Misprints are galore too (what is $k$ in $k>2$?). It seems like the journal had a really bad luck with this particular problem. I think we should wait a bit before doing anything. Maybe someone will figure it out...

Comment: To me the solution seems incorrect, and perhaps one issue comes from confusing e.g. $v_n \equiv 3 \mod{8}$ and $n \equiv 3 \mod{8}$ in the proposed solution. See for example in the second part: it is true as the author says that if $n \equiv 3 \mod{8}$, then $v_n \equiv 0 \mod{17}$. But in the solution the argument seems to be that "$v_n \equiv 3 \mod{8}$, so $v_n \equiv 0 \mod{17}$" which is false.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman Indeed, I think any argument that is just a finite list of modulo arguments cannot suffice here because whatever finite list of moduli one rights down, if $n$ is congruent to 0 with respect to every modulus you have will not have any forced divisibility.

Comment: @JoshuaZ Yes, they issued a subsequent correction.